Vuetify validate a custom form component containing multiple internal form components
I have seen several posted questions with similar titles.  For example, Vuetify apply rules validation to a custom component.  However, they either (like that one) reference a situation where the rules can just be passed to a single internal form field component, or don't have an answer at all.  To the communities defense, the questions that are closer to mine are typically poorly posed or unnecessarily complicated.  So, I will try to pose a clear simple case that demonstrates my issue, in hopes that there is a simple answer.
Say I want to create a custom component <MyTextArea> that contains two  fields, and I have validation rules that depend upon both of those fields.  For example, I might want to be able to specify a rule that requires one and only one of the fields to be non-empty.
From what I have been able to find, I expect I would need to create a MyTextArea.vue file that looks something like
<script setup>
const model = defineModel()
const props = defineProps({
    rules: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
    }
}
</script>
<template>
<v-textarea label="field a" v-model="model.a"></v-textarea><br/>
<v-textarea label="field b" v-model="model.b"></v-textarea>
</template>

And where when I am using the component I want to be able to write
<v-form>
    ...
    <MyTextArea v-model="my_model" :rules="[value => !!value.a != !!value.b]" />
    ...
</v-form>

Since I can't just pass the specified rules on, I would expect that I need to implement a function in MyTextArea.vue that runs the rules, and returns the result, but I haven't found an example or any documentation on how to do this.
Any answers, including "hey bozo its right here at https:...", would be very welcome.
Thanks

Vuetify uses a composable (useValidation()), which registers a value ref to be part of its parent VForm validation. Pass the props of MyTextArea to the composable and use the returned refs, like errorMessage and validationClasses, in your component. Sill, this is probably less comfortable than using the inputs directly.

Thanks.  I am still surprised there isn't more documentation for this use case.
